# How to remove Dark bar below toolbar on navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, navigation-drawer

I am very confused of seeing dark bar below toolbar on navigation drawer.I tried many of the ways to remove it.But.,nothing works as excepted.You can see a dark rectangular bar on top of the Home.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8fAK.png]

Anyone Knows to fix this.Please help me...

appbarlayout is,

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="com.jrs.medicare.DoctorHome">

   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_doctor_home" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

acitivity layout is,

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_doctor_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_doctor_home_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: set app:elevation="0dp"

Comment: How can do it.? is it in activity.?

Comment: if you used appbar layout then put in there or in toolbar

Comment: not working dude...

Answer (score 0):

I think may I can help,
use app:elevation="0dp" -if you are using support library (for supporting old versions of Android) 
or use android:elevation - if you are not using support library.

Comment: where can i do it.? toolbar.?

Comment: if you are using a llibrary for nav drawer like this(android.support.design.widget........) put elevation under this tag

Comment: @Suhail code for you app_bar layout and navigatiview layout

Comment: i did n't get it.where should i add elevtion in my xml..please check it..

Answer (score 0):

just remove `android:layout_marginTop="80dp"` from your `NavigationView`

like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
  android:id="@+id/nav_view"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_gravity="start"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  app:menu="@menu/activity_doctor_home_drawer" />
```

Comment: If i remove margintop how can i implement navigation drawer as in the picture.if i do it.,navigation drawer overlap with notification status bar.I dont like it.,I want to appear navigation drawer like this without the dark bar.How to do that dear.?

Comment: try to add top padding the `android:layout_marginTop="80dp"` reason for that shadow else is your choice my friend

Comment: did you remove `android:layout_marginTop="80dp"` @Suhail

Comment: yep.now navigation drawer overlap with status bar.I want to appear it below of the toolbar by coinsiding withit.Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have removed black bar.

1) adding layout_marginTop = "60dp" (as per your toolbar size) in Main layout of Header file added in NavigationDrawer.

2) remove marginTop from NavigationDrawer.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to Main Activity

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

then add padding_top to 
in app_bar_main.xml